# gsutil stop notification error with 'NotFoundException: 404'

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I' m attempting to stop one of two channels notification. I got an error after entering this command.

```
C:\Python27>python D:\gsutil\gsutil notification stopchannel 99467068-b556-4664-
a32a-f593cf1d50df WTgOzw4yFEJQxhSZqCq_7-g3Rro
Removing channel 99467068-b556-4664-a32a-f593cf1d50df with resource identifier W
TgOzw4yFEJQxhSZqCq_7-g3Rro ...
**NotFoundException: 404**
```

Anyone please suggest how to fix it.

Regards,

Comment: Are you still receiving notifications for the channel?

Comment: Yes jterrace, We are still receiving notification for that channel. Any idea.

Comment: You can find the channel and resource in the body of the notification messages. Are you sure they match?

Comment: Hi jterrace, This is my body.
X-Goog-Resource-Id: WTgOzw4yFEJQxhSZqCq_7-g3Rro
Content-Length: 1059
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
X-Goog-Resource-Uri: https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/item_activity_log/o?alt=json&prettyPrint=True&projection=FULL&alt=json
X-Goog-Message-Number: 2442044539
User-Agent: APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)
Host: emerald-metrics-636.appspot.com
Content_Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content_Length: 1059
X-Goog-Channel-Id: 99467068-b556-4664-a32a-f593cf1d50df
Accept: */*
X-Goog-Resource-State: exists

Comment: Are you using a service account with gsutil? You must use a service account tied to the same project that created the notification channel.

Comment: Hi jterrace, I have tried to re-config my gsutil to make sure that it must use a service account tied to the same project with notificaiton channel. The result shown the same error 'NotFoundException: 404'

Comment: Could you send an email will all the relevant information to gs-team@google.com ?

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am using service account and my channel Id and resource Id matches. Anyone know the reason behind this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issues as well.